# Unable to print all frame data received from xbee in byte array in Python

Tags: python, xbee, zigbee

While Receiving frames from xbee i am getting 3 frames, but in byte array its showing data of only one frame. How to get all the 3 frame data in byte array?
I am using these two commands to read data and print the data in byte array.

```
xbee_message =local_device.read_data()
data = xbee_message.data
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved:
Just do the loop.

```
x=""
for i in range(2):
    xbee_message = local_device.read_data()
    #print(xbee_message)
    x = x + xbee_message.data.hex()
```